# How to change color of text with javascript at event

Tags: javascript, html

The code works to change the background color.

`regionLinks[i].style.backgroundColor = (regionRow === selection[0].row) ? '#ff7700' : null`

But I want to change the text color instead of the background color. How can I do that?
The html that is manipulated is

`'<div data-row="' + i + '"><a class="region" href="/' + data.getValue(i, 0) + '">' + data.getValue(i, 0) + '</a></div>'`

My aim is to make the text in the link have the new text color at this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style property is called *color*

```
regionLinks[i].style.color
```

Answer (score 1):

The `color` is the property for text color.

If `regionLinks[i]` is the anchor then `regionLinks[i].style.color = '#123456';`
if it is the div `regionLinks[i].firstChild.style.color = '#123456';`

Anchors are styled by the UA, so to overwrite them you have to target it specifically.